# make mysql query more efficient

Tags: mysql, sql, database

so at the minute my initial query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    `surveyEntries`.`ID` AS EntryID,
    `surveyEntries`.`created` AS EntryDate,
    `hw_services`.`name` AS Provider, 
    `surveyQuestions`.`ID` AS QuestionID,
    `surveyQuestions`.`label` AS Question, 
    `survey_meta`.`answer` AS Answer,
    `surveyQuestions`.`parentID` AS ParentQuestion
FROM `survey` , `surveyQuestions` , `surveyEntries` , `survey_meta` , `hw_services`
WHERE `survey`.`ID` =2
    AND `survey`.`ID` = `surveyQuestions`.`surveyID`
    AND `survey`.`ID` = `surveyEntries`.`surveyID`
    AND `surveyEntries`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`entryID`
    AND `hw_services`.`ID` = `surveyEntries`.`hw_serviceID`
    AND `surveyQuestions`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`questionID`
```

Now i have read around and this is a very weak lengthy query that could be optimised.

Does any one know how i could do this? my attempt failed to provide the same result which is below:

```
SELECT 
    `surveyEntries`.`ID` AS EntryID,
    `surveyEntries`.`created` AS EntryDate,
    `hw_services`.`name` AS Provider,
    `surveyQuestions`.`ID` AS QuestionID,
    `surveyQuestions`.`label` AS Question,
    `survey_meta`.`answer` AS Answer,
    `surveyQuestions`.`parentID` AS ParentQuestion
FROM `survey`
    JOIN `surveyQuestions` 
        ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyQuestions`.`surveyID`
    JOIN `surveyEntries`
        ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyEntries`.`surveyID`
    JOIN `survey_meta`
        ON `survey`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`entryID`
    JOIN `hw_services` 
        ON `survey`.`ID` = `hw_services`.`ID`
WHERE `survey`.`ID` =2
```

**EDIT::**

Okay so after looking at your comments i can see why, silly mistake.

A few of the joins are actually joining two tables together instead of joining them to the FROM table (survey).

This is my new attempt which has failed.

```
SELECT 
`surveyEntries`.`ID` AS EntryID,
`surveyEntries`.`created` AS EntryDate,
`hw_services`.`name` AS Provider,
`surveyQuestions`.`ID` AS QuestionID,
`surveyQuestions`.`label` AS Question,
`survey_meta`.`answer` AS Answer,
`surveyQuestions`.`parentID` AS ParentQuestion
FROM `survey`
JOIN `surveyQuestions` 
    ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyQuestions`.`surveyID`

JOIN `surveyEntries`
    ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyEntries`.`surveyID`

JOIN `survey_meta`
    ON `surveyEntries`.`surveyID` = `survey_meta`.`entryID`

JOIN `hw_services` 
    ON `hw_services`.`ID` = `surveyEntries `.`hw_serviceID`

JOIN `surveyQuestions` 
    ON `surveyQuestions`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`questionID`

WHERE `survey`.`ID` =2
```

The error i get is : Not unique table/alias: 'surveyQuestions'

Comment: Looks like the same query, just old style joins in the first one, and new explicit joins in the second. Executes the same way.

Comment: Thats what i thought, however the first query brings back the correct results and the second query brings back none

Comment: The two forms of the query you gave should give a similar (if not the same) result under the hood of MySQL.  Most people prefer the `JOIN` version because it is explicit as to what is happening.

Comment: The last two join conditions are different. In fact first query has 5 comparisons of ID, second only 4

Comment: Then why is it bringing back 0 results, thats confusing me

Comment: If you really must do away with some many `JOIN`s then you can consider denormalizing your schema a bit.  But I would only do this if it would not cause storage problems.

Comment: Yeah, the `join` conditions are different. The query is not same, thus it gives different result.

Comment: arh @paulF that is it, the last two are not directly joining to `survey` how would i achieve this ?

Comment: In order to get accurate answer, you should probably run `EXPLAIN your_query_here` and write the output with your problem. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) what EXPLAIN is.

Comment: i have edited my question if you guys can take a look

Comment: Just to comment on the edit - to fix doing it this way you would need to give the second join of surveyQuestions an alias (_JOIN surveyQuestions AS sq2_) & use that alias in the ON condition. But that would mean it is being treated as an additional table & may cause the query to be less efficient.

Comment: If you need to optimize the query - look at what @Pholochtairze has suggested. If the query plan looks like it could be improved - check out the documentation on STRAIGHT_JOIN & FORCE INDEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
`surveyEntries`.`ID` AS EntryID,
`surveyEntries`.`created` AS EntryDate,
`hw_services`.`name` AS Provider,
`surveyQuestions`.`ID` AS QuestionID,
`surveyQuestions`.`label` AS Question,
`survey_meta`.`answer` AS Answer,
`surveyQuestions`.`parentID` AS ParentQuestion
FROM `survey`
JOIN `surveyQuestions` 
    ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyQuestions`.`surveyID`
JOIN `surveyEntries`
    ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyEntries`.`surveyID`
JOIN `survey_meta`
     ON (`surveyEntries`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`entryID` AND `surveyQuestions`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`questionID`)
JOIN `hw_services` 
    ON `surveyEntries`.`hw_serviceID` = `hw_services`.`ID`
WHERE `survey`.`ID` =2
```

Comment: error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`surveyEntries`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`entryID` AND ` surveyQuestions`.`ID` = `s' at line 15

Comment: and before you edited the answer it threw : Not unique table/alias: 'surveyQuestions'

Comment: now i get #1054 - Unknown column ' surveyQuestions.ID' in 'on clause'

Comment: there was an extra space after the back-quote - without having a matching schema to test with it's hard to spot the cut&paste faults :-(

Comment: Thats fine, this query worked fine, thanks for your help!